# TabControl_DrawItem tab color from Right to left

Tags: vb.net, tabcontrol, right-to-left

I'm trying to change tab control tab color by OwnerDrawFixed and I have this code bellow working perfectly, but I have multiple language application and I need to change the layout from lift to right and from right to left depends on application language, I need help to make this code drowse from right to left when the RightToLiftLayout = true, and from left to right (current code) when its false.

thank you .

```vb
'Firstly we'll define some parameters.
Dim CurrentTab As TabPage = TabControl1.TabPages(e.Index)
Dim ItemRect As Rectangle = TabControl1.GetTabRect(e.Index)
Dim FillBrush As New SolidBrush(Color.Red)
Dim TextBrush As New SolidBrush(Color.White)
Dim sf As New StringFormat
sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center
sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center

'If we are currently painting the Selected TabItem we'll 
'change the brush colors and inflate the rectangle.
If CBool(e.State And DrawItemState.Selected) Then
    FillBrush.Color = Color.White
    TextBrush.Color = Color.Red
    ItemRect.Inflate(2, 2)
End If

'Set up rotation for left and right aligned tabs
If TabControl1.Alignment = TabAlignment.Left Or TabControl1.Alignment = TabAlignment.Right Then
    Dim RotateAngle As Single = 90
    If TabControl1.Alignment = TabAlignment.Left Then RotateAngle = 270
    Dim cp As New PointF(ItemRect.Left + (ItemRect.Width \ 2), ItemRect.Top + (ItemRect.Height \ 2))
    e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(cp.X, cp.Y)
    e.Graphics.RotateTransform(RotateAngle)
    ItemRect = New Rectangle(-(ItemRect.Height \ 2), -(ItemRect.Width \ 2), ItemRect.Height, ItemRect.Width)
End If

'Next we'll paint the TabItem with our Fill Brush
e.Graphics.FillRectangle(FillBrush, ItemRect)

'Now draw the text.
e.Graphics.DrawString(CurrentTab.Text, e.Font, TextBrush, RectangleF.op_Implicit(ItemRect), sf)

'Reset any Graphics rotation
e.Graphics.ResetTransform()

'Finally, we should Dispose of our brushes.
FillBrush.Dispose()
TextBrush.Dispose()
```

Comment: You'll get mirrored strings when you draw the text if both  the RightToLeftLayout and RightToLeft properties are true. Read the [Remarks](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.righttoleftlayout?view=netframework-4.8). Alternatively, set the `Alignment` property to `TabAlignment.Right` and don't change the `RightToLeftLayout`. Check the source code of [this](https://github.com/q8soft/WinFrmSkins.NYX/blob/master/src/NYX/NYXTabControl.vb) `TabControl ` which supports all the tab alignments. Also check the other controls there, all support RTL layout.

Comment: Use the [`TextRenderer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textrenderer?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) to draw the Top and Bottom alignments regardless of the layout (ltr, rtl) and language. The text will be rendered correctly. Use the `Graphics.DrawString` for the other two alignments since the former doesn't support drawing strings vertically. Disabling the `TabControl`'s visual style and/or copying its Parent's background helps to reduce possible drawing distortions when you draw the control while it's mirrored.

Answer (score 0):

This is untested but I think that you should be able to change this:

```vb
Dim sf As New StringFormat
```

to this:

```vb
Dim sf = If(RightToLeft,
            New StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.DirectionRightToLeft),
            New StringFormat)
```

You may need to use `RightToLeftLayout` rather than `RightToLeft`. I'm not sure as it's not something that I've ever done.

Comment: Unfortunately not working, my problem is how to make it draw from right yo left.

Comment: @Rabeeaqabaha According to the rotation angles in your code, try: `Dim sf As New StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.DirectionRightToLeft Or StringFormatFlags.DirectionVertical) With {.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center, .LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center}`, comment the transform part and see the result.

Comment: @JQSOFT its still draw on the left side of the screen, but now the text draw vertically.
https://g.top4top.io/p_1567ccvyg1.png

Comment: @Rabeeaqabaha Use this flag `StringFormatFlags.DirectionVertical` only when the `Alignment` is left or right. I can understand what are you trying to do, if you read my comment on your post carefully. Not possible to get the RTL characters drawn correctly if you enable the both RTL properties. You'll get something like `ربيع` drawn like `ع ي ب ر`. I believe you've already noticed that.

Comment: @JQSOFT yes I know it will draw the text like you said, I will read Microsoft doc about RightToLeftLayout hope I can fined solution , if you know a custom tab control simple but can be change the tabs color.